# Refactoring, changing DataSource types based on selectedIndexChanged event, C#

Tags: c#, wcf, refactoring

I am dealing with a web application.  What is asked of me is that when the page loads, that my drop down list displays index 0, with specific properties to display and store.

Based on that, there is a second down list to hold a list.

Next on the `selectedIndexChanged` event, should my index in ddl1 (I'll call it), the data in ddl2 should change.

The data being populated is all from a database query.

I'm in the process of refactoring, and i am trying to find a way so that I can just pass some data to a `bindControls` method.  I'm having passing a general data type that could be cast based on a boolean value I am also passing to the method.

Here's an example

```
IQueryable<BankAccount> accountQuery = db.BankAccounts.Where(x => x.ClientId 
== clientId && x.AccountNumber != accountNumber);


private void bindControls(DropDownList ddl, string textFieldProp, string 
dataFieldProp, boolean isBillPayment, object dataSource)
{
    //this is where my confusion is... i don't know how to change the type
    //of the object
    if(isBillPayment == true)
       dataSource = typeof(IQueryable<BankAccount>);
     ddlDataSource = dataSource.ToList()
     ddlDataTextField = textFieldProp;
     ddlDataValueField = dataFieldProp;
     ddl.DataBind();
}
```

I know there HAS to be a way that I can assign this data source to what I want. 
the query i posted is just an example of what that data source is going to , i have three different possible table queries from either BankAccounts, TransactionTypes, or Payees.

sorry i should have mentioned that, im sorry to for any confusion with it.  Maybe that makes more sense now

Comment: Your posted code makes no sense. Why do you want to change the type? Why are you showing us `accountQuery` but its not used in your code.

Answer (score 0):

Use generics:

```
private void bindControls<IQueryable<T>>(DropDownList ddl, string textFieldProp, string 
dataFieldProp, boolean isBillPayment, IQueryable<T> dataSource)
{
    // I don't think you really need this.
    // if(isBillPayment == true)
    //    dataSource = typeof(IQueryable<T>);

    ddlDataSource = dataSource.ToList()
    ddlDataTextField = textFieldProp;
    ddlDataValueField = dataFieldProp;
    ddl.DataBind();
}
```

I would recommend casting `.ToList()` earlier and passing that to your `bindControls()` method instead of `IQueryable`.

... but I don't really understand *why* you're doing it this way.  In my opinion, you don't need your boolean switch.

Comment: you're right... the boolean is totally not needed... i've since tried setting IQueryable<object> dataSource, as a method parameter, 
and the casting later .. ddl.DataSource = (IQueryable<BankAccount>)dataSource.ToList();
does that look like a decent approach?

Comment: If you use generics, you don't have to cast from `object`.  You've got `IQueryable<T>` so you're good - unless I misunderstand.

Comment: is there a using statement needed for visual studio to recognize <T> ?  That may seem like a rookie comment but i keep getting the red underline from hell whenever i type in IQueryable<T>... red underline under the T... i thought thats how it is identified  as generic...?  i dont mean to comment with a question but it pertains to your reply...